# jQuery/Javascript if css right > go to this css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

Can anyone tell me why the conditional in my code is never true?

http://jsfiddle.net/eygLU/2/

Solved:

It's because I was checking a string against a number and needed to use `parseInt()`

Comment: Don't forget to also post your javascript in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `parseInt()`:

```
$('.zeppelin').css('right') > winWidth
```

`$('.zeppelin').css('right')` will return `[integer]px`. Therefore you are comparing a string type to an integer type.

Try:

```
parseInt($('.zeppelin').css('right')) > winWidth
```

---

Also, as a side note, looking through your code, you have:

```
'-'+zepWidth
```

If you wish to invert an integer, multiply it by `-1` instead:

```
(zepWidth*-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Curt mentioned, you were missing a parseInt, but you also needed to stop the animation so when you reset it, the div did not fly back accross the screen:

also needed

```
overflow: hidden
```

on the html and body to get rid of scroll bar

http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/eygLU/4/

EDIT: Also it was not resetting because you didn't have a +"px" after "-"+zepWidth

EDIT: update link